# Recommend UI modifications

Tags: jquery, user-interface, faceted-search

I am looking to modify the "faceted filter" on our schedule page and would like some input on what kind of UI elements I could use to enhance the experience. The current one is woefully bad and the city/miles section really doesn't work correctly, it was originally built using zip codes and converted to using cities.

What would be some good UI elements to use here and how would you see this thing working?

The URL is http://www.scic.com/schedule

The page does not validate, please don't crucify me for that, I only started work here a month ago.

I have been building a demo using the multiselect widget ( http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget ) for the states but not sure what I should use for the other parts.

Comment: You might want to consider asking this on the UI Stack Exchange: http://ux.stackexchange.com/ .  You might get more answers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

The date selector control is very confusing in terms of what you're actually selecting. Also, why is it only limited to displaying 4 months at a time?

There are some missing mouse-over states which would help indicate what is clickable. For instance if you mouse over the month you get the carrot instead of the hand so unless you click it you don't know that you can. (Same goes for other places like checkboxes within the sate selector)

State currently does not have any relation to the City field which is not such good practive. If a user selects a specific state, then only the cities for that state should be visible within the cities drop-down.